# How to get id from a href link during popup

Tags: php, jquery, html, popup

I wish to get 'id' value from  href tag.

When i click the  tag the popup will shown , but i want id value within popup

HTML

```
            <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" id="<?php echo $rows['vid'];?>" class="p-buy ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left">View Now</a></div>
```

i want this 'id' value in popup it will come like id='1' ,id='2',..

'id' value shown properly in inspect area. But i am not getting this value to my popup

POPUP HTML

```
    <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" class="ui-content" style="min-width:250px;">
  <form method="post" action="">
    <div>
      <h3>Please fill below information</h3>
      <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="text" name="vids" id="vids" placeholder="video id">
      <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Email Id:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
      <label for="pswd" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Mobile:</label>
      <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Then i use JQuery for to get the ID. But when i click the  tag it does not go to ready function also

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   alert("ready");
   $("a").click(function()
   {
      alert("click");
      var pos = $(this).attr('id');
      alert(pos);
      $('#vids').val(pos);
   });
 });
```

Please help me anyone i stucked long time with this.

**Thanks** in advance

Comment: I tried on JSFiddle, it works fine, it return me <?php echo $rows['vid'];?> on the Video ID field, so as long as you have $rows as a var in your php file it should be fine

Comment: works as expected! https://jsbin.com/koqecajalu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I am not getting. Script not working for me, even ready function also not working

Comment: have you added jquery script

Comment: Its my mistake i added script under footer. Now i changed to in header section. working fine. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve id in variable you can use document.getElementByTagName('href') and store into variable x. Then document.write(x.id) should write id of href.